# COM interop control causes "Out of memory" error

Tags: com, vb6, interop

I have written a COM interop control for CefSharp using VB.NET which I consume in VB6 as an OCX.

Sometimes, it works, but then again sometimes when then control is shown, VB6 can not load it and tells me "Out of memory".
The form log file says "Line 21: Control WinformsCefSharp1 could not be loaded."

Or it might go fine, but when I close the form, the error is shown.

Should it theoretically work, and I just have to find out where exactely it goes wrong, or are there situations where it's just impossible to avoid these errors because of unfixed bugs in VB6 or so?

Once the error has occured, I have to close Visual Basic 6 and re-open it, else it would throw an error and not start again.

So I think that Visual Basic 6 has some files locked, and in the task manager I see 3 CefSharpSubprocesses.

I can also reliably raise the error by calling

```
Public Sub DoShutdown()

    browser.Dispose()
    CefSharp.Cef.Shutdown() 'It does not matter if I switch the lines, the error occurs always

End Sub
```

I have a crazy idea: What if I wrap the COM object into a .NET dll? Would that help?

Comment: *"are there situations where it's just impossible to avoid these errors because of unfixed bugs in VB6"*  -- no, I don't think that is the case.

Comment: You should add more detail so people can actually see the minimum to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this will solve your problem but I faced a similar situation when I used interop libraries.

COM objects have to be released, otherwise your application won't quit properly. Here's how I dispose an object of type Range when I don't need it anymore:

```
Excel.Range range= _oSourceSheet.get_Range("A1", "C3");
// some code
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);
```

And, when I have to quit the application:

```
oApplication.Quit();
ReleaseCOMObject(objectsToRelease);

GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Yep, I call the GC twice, here's a [link](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2013/11/05/release-excel-com-objects/) with a complete explanation. It's written in C# but should be valid to VB6 too.